# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting mad cause I have a situation where I am trying to modify the quantity of an item via a custom action and I don´t know why what works in one view doesn´t in another, probably it is something stupid but I can´t find the reason, the action add_item works perfectly, but update_item_quantity doesn´t even display de view and shows this exception:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

here is my code:

routes.rb:

```
  resources :designs
  resources :carts
  resources :cart_items do
    get :add_to_cart, on: :member
    post :add_item, on: :member
    post :update_item_quantity, on: :member
  end
```

Te controllers are as following:

cart_items_controller.rb

```
def add_item
    @cart_item = CartItem.new(add_item_params)
    @design = Design.find(params[:design_id])
    @cart = Cart.find(current_user.cart_id)

    @cart_item.design_id = @design.id
    @cart_item.cart_id = current_user.cart_id
    if @cart_item.save
        flash[:success] = "Design succesfully added to active cart"
        redirect_to cart_path(@cart)
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Design couldn´t be added to your cart"
        redirect_to designs_path
    end
end

def update_item_quantity
    @cart = Cart.find(current_user.cart_id)
    @cart_item= CartItem.find(params(:cart_item_id))


    redirect_to cart_path(@cart)
end

private

def add_item_params
    params.require(:cart_item).permit(:quantity)
end
```

And the views are:

/cart_items/add_to_cart.html.erb:

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <p>Add design: <%= @design.name %></p>
    </div>
    <% if current_user.cart_active? %>
        <div class="col-md-4 tdp-add-to-cart-panel">
            <p>Click on the button below if you want to add this design to the cart you have active at this moment</p>
            <%= form_for @cart_item, url: {controller: 'cart_items', action: "add_item", params: {design_id: @design.id}} do |f| %>
            <span class="">Qty: </span>
            <span class=""><%= f.number_field (:quantity, min: '1', max: '100', step: '1') %></span>
            <span class=""><%= f.submit "Add design", class: "btn btn-login" %></span>
            <% end %>
            <%#= button_to "Add to current cart", {:controller => :carts, :action => :add_item_to_active_cart, :design_id => @design.id }, class: "btn-lg btn-login" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And here is /carts/show.html.erb

```
<h2>Cart, <%= @cart.name %></h2>

    <div class="col-md-8 tdp-listing cart-content-listing">
        <% @cart_items.each do |ci|  %>
            <div class="row tdp-listing-row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <%= ci.design.name %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <%= ci.design.price * ci.quantity %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <%= form_for @cart_item, url: {controller: "cart_items", action: "update_item_quantity", params: {cart_item_id: ci.id}} do |f| %>
                        <span class="">Qty: ci.id <%= ci.id %> </span>
                        <span class=""><%#= f.number_field(:quantity, min: '1', max: '100', step: '1') %></span>
                        <span class=""><%#= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-login" %></span>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-md-1">
                    <%= link_to "Delete", cart_item_path(ci), method: :delete, 
                                data: { confirm: "Are you sure that you want to delete this item?" }, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Wait for your news and thanks in advance.

Antonio

Comment: Change `form_for @cart_item` to `form_for ci` in your `carts/show.html.erb`.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much, it worked perfectly. I owe you one, and a big one.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your code for the `CartsController#show` action as well as the whole exception message too.

I guess you have not assigned any value to the instance variable `@cart_items` in the `show` action. That's why `<% @cart_items.each do |ci|  %>` on line 4 is failing to assign any value to `ci` in the `/carts/show.html.erb` template.

This should be the reason why your form is throwing exception for containing `nil` value.